# ActiveRecordModel.group(:attribute).count with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

When trying to run such code in Postgres I always get errors of this kind:

```
Caused by PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "<table name>.<some random column>" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

LINE 1: ...ments" GROUP BY "<table_name>"."<:attribute>" ORDER BY ...

Answer (score 0):

There was something on the default scope that was preventing this to work. I managed to sort this out by using `ActiveRecordModel.unscoped.group(:attribute).count`